# CoreOS Fleet Unit file and Docker Dynamic Port issue

Tags: docker, systemd, coreos

I am currently trying to get a dynamic port so I can register it with etcd on CoreOS. This is proving very difficult.

Here is my Unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=test Elastic Search Server
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
User=core
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull shizzle/elasticsearch-server
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/docker start -a %n || /usr/bin/docker run --name="%n" -p :9200 -p :9300 shizzle/elasticsearch-server /elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Des.config=/etc/elasticsearch.yml'
ExecStartPost=-/usr/bin/etcdctl mkdir /%n
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/etcdctl set /%n/host %H
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/etcdctl set /%n/port $(docker inspect --format='{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "9200/tcp") 0).HostPort}}' %n)"
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop /%n
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/etcdctl rm /%n
```

Unfortunately, the third ExecStartPost fails. Any help would be much appreciated, I'm stumped!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a host level registration service to register the containers with ports to etcd? Something like https://github.com/progrium/registrator might be able to do what you are trying to do in shell. Short of that, I have had success registering IP and port pairs in CoreOS using something like this:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "port=$(docker inspect -f '{{range $i, $e := .NetworkSettings.Ports }}{{$p := index $e 0}}{{$p.HostPort}}{{end}}' %n); while netstat -lnt | grep :$port >/dev/null; do etcdctl set /app/upstream/%n $COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4:$port --ttl 300 >/dev/null; sleep 200; done"
```

You might be able to adapt that to just do port.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using absolute path for docker binary (/usr/bin/docker) can it be the cause?

What error does it print?

Comment: He is in a shell for the `ExecStartPost` command, so `$PATH` is available and the `docker` command doesn't need to be absolute.